# Jira SVN / Subversion Plugin does not synchronize / update after initial sync

Tags: svn, jira, jira-plugin

I've gone ahead and installed the Subverion plugin and it did the initial sync of the repository so that I can see the check-ins at the task level however it does not see any subsequent changes. My understanding is that there is a scheduled job that should poll SVN periodically but that doesn't seem to be running. I examined the catalina.out log and there are no errors or mention of an SVN sync running.

Do I need to setup a job? How can I adjust the polling period?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1):

To change the polling period you need to sysadmin privileges in JIRA. If you have that goto:

Administration-> System -> Services and look for Subversion Revision Indexing Service where the polling period can be adjusted (default 60 min)

I'm using JIRA 5.2 so its possible the navigation is slightly different in other versions. See this page:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA052/Services